# I need to combine "functions" with "for loop" with php

Tags: php, function, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a program that gives an oputput like:

x

xx

xxx

xxxx

xxxxx

xxxx

xxx

xx

x

I have a similar program which is:

```
<?php
    $n = 4;                                     
    $R[] = '*';                                  
    $w = 1;                                     
        for( $c=1; $c<=$n; $c++ ){             
            $R[] = '*'.str_repeat( '*',$w );  
            $w = $w+1;                       
        }        
    print '<pre>'.implode( "\n",$R ).'</pre>';  
?>
```

but i need to use a function and create an other loop for an easier code.
I also need to decrease it after 5th row.
thanx in advance...

Comment: "I need to use a function" ... for which part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
function drawPyramid($length) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; ++$i) {
        echo str_repeat("x", $i) . "\n";
    }
    for ($i = $length - 1; $i > 0; --$i) {
        echo str_repeat("x", $i) . "\n";
    }
}

drawPyramid(3);
echo "\n";
drawPyramid(5);
```

Comment: Kinda like that but each row must increase one "x" till "xxxxx" than decrease to one "x".

Comment: That's what it does indeed. You are not seeing it properly in browser probably, replace `\n` with `<br>` or render it in `<pre/>`.

Comment: That's what it does, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly like i need.

Comment: Awesome, please don't forget to mark the question as closed when available so it's treated properly.

Answer (score 4):

Given the problem description I would just use recursion, because it's a more elegant way.

```
function hump($n, $i = 1)
{
        echo str_repeat('*', $i), PHP_EOL;
        if ($i < $n) {
                hump($n, $i + 1);
                echo str_repeat('*', $i), PHP_EOL;
        }
}

hump(5);
```

It prints one level in each invocation and calls itself to print the next level until it reaches the top; when the stack unwinds it prints the same level again.

For performance and/or memory optimisations it's advisable to use loops rather than recursion.

Comment: Yeap that also works urahara. 
It is a little more coplicated than i need but thanks.

Comment: @user1694673 If the requirement was high performance I would have just picked two for loops, but I felt this was more elegant :)

Comment: I must say, as long as recursion isn't necessary, then don't use recursion. Recursive calls are slow because they consume a lot of memory

Comment: @RonaldBorla whether or not recursion should be used depends on the situation and not on such axioms. Also, even though PHP doesn't support it yet and this problem is harder to write as such, tail recursive code doesn't exhibit such memory problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution, getting rid of the for loop completely:

```
function addLevel(&$array, $currentDepth, $maxDepth)
{
    $array[] = str_repeat('*', $currentDepth);
    if($currentDepth < $maxDepth)
    {
        addLevel($array, $currentDepth + 1, $maxDepth);
        $array[] = str_repeat('*', $currentDepth);
    }
}

$R= array();

addLevel($R, 1, 5);

print '<pre>'.implode( "\n",$R ).'</pre>';
```

It's not exactly neat, that the thing has 3 parameters, but without a class to do this, you would need to use global variables, which is even worse.

Answer (score 2):

Nice homework assignment. Nice seeing all the different examples.

How about a 1-liner?

```
for ($i=1; $i<$loops*2; $i++) echo str_repeat('*',($i > $loops ? ($loops * 2) - $i : $i)) . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

**Examples**

```
echo "<pre>";
echo drawOutput(5, "x");
echo drawOutput(5, "x ");
echo drawOutput(5, "x ", " "); // left padding
echo drawOutput(5, "@-^-@ ", " "); // left padding
```

**Output**

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx                          <----------------- what you want 
xxxx
xxx
xx
x


x 
x x 
x x x 
x x x x 
x x x x x                      <----------------- Space it out
x x x x 
x x x 
x x 
x 


    x 
   x x 
  x x x 
 x x x x 
x x x x x                      <----------------- Add some padding
 x x x x 
  x x x 
   x x 
    x 



    @-^-@ 
   @-^-@ @-^-@ 
  @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ 
 @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ 
@-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ 
 @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ 
  @-^-@ @-^-@ @-^-@ 
   @-^-@ @-^-@ 
    @-^-@
```

**Function Used**

```
function drawOutput($length, $str = "* ", $lpad = null) {
    $x = array();
    for($n = $i = $length; $i >= 0; $i --) {
        $x[] = ($lpad ? str_repeat($lpad, $i) : null) . str_repeat($str, $n - $i) . "\n";
    }
    return implode($x) . implode(array_slice(array_reverse($x), 1));
}
```